# Spyder Application fails to Launch [ No module named 'PySide' ]

Tags: python, spyder, pyside

I am getting the below error when I am trying to launch Spyder..

```
  File "C:\Users\vinay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
****ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'****
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Make sure you have `PySide` installed

Comment: install some Qt backend as pyqt5

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is usually caused by install PyQt5 with pip. Please see [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to understand how to fix that.